# Page tab - Like using Open Graph meta tags showing the wrong site name.

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am implementing a page tab application and in that app I have likes. I am using the [open graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) to define what shows up when one likes a page. This is what my tags look like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My apps title" runat = "server"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" runat = "server"/>
<meta  property="og:url" content="current/page/url" runat = "server"/>
<meta  property="og:image" content="path/to/image.png" runat = "server"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=" The name of the site" runat = "server"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="The description" runat = "server"/>
```

For the most part this works as intended, when I run the debugger Facebook parses the url fine and all th returned data looks in order. As I mentioned before I am running this in a page tab, the canvas points to a site I am hosting but which I don't want associated with the tab. That is, I only intend for the application to be viewed through the page tab and I don't want the domain it is hosted on to show up when someone likes something in the page tab.

The problem is this, when someone does like something within the site I get the following output:
Title of the app - correct
www.mydomain.com - NOT what I want!
Description of the app - correct

I've defined an Open Graph tag for site name. When I run my urls through the debugger I don't see my domain anywhere in the response(what I want) however when we actually like something I get the domain!

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or how I could fix it? I've done some Googling and can't find an answer however I'm sure I'm not the only one who has faced this time of problem before. Any advice would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What exactly get’s liked – your Facebook page, or some of your own Open Graph objects? (Just to be clear: The “Like” button on top of every page tab that gets automatically placed there always likes the Facebook page itself!)

Comment: Hi, the page gets liked but it is populated using the open graph tags. The tags all get parsed properly except for the site_name, it seems to default to the domain the page is hosted on.